# Does every protein encoding gene necessarily have a transcription factor?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, dna, proteins, transcription-factor

For instance, transcription factor **gene A** is responsible for activating **gene B** that encodes **protein 1**.

However, it is possible for genes like **gene B** to encode proteins without having transcription factors to activate them?

(Otherwise said, can protein encoding genes have no transcription factors)?